# Asp.Net Identity with custom UserStore, overload inaccessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, ravendb

I am implementing ASP.NET Identity via RavenDB and try to add roles to my user. https://github.com/ILMServices/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/blob/master/RavenDB.AspNet.Identity/UserStore.cs

This implementation has the following overload available `public Task AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)`

The `ApplicationUserManager` is derived from `UserManager` but I am unable to reach the overload. The only method available is the base method `AddToRoleAsync(string UserId, string role)`.

The Store property is a public property in the UserManager base class, so it doesn't look anything special is going on there.

I also tried doing a direct call to `manager.Store.AddToRoleAsync` but again I am not getting the overloaded method back with intellisense.

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction, really stuck here.

[image: When I create the UserStore the member is accessible:]
[image: After I created the ApplicationUserManager with the UserStore the member is hidden]
And then ofcourse my controller inherits this issue, and this started my search to why this is happening.

[image: Controller Action]

**In Reponse to CodeNotFound, here is the ApplicationUser. It is quite simple.**

```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IEntity
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }


        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can show us the code of your ApplicationUser ?

Comment: I added the class to my initial post

Answer (score 0):

It is because you need to write in your custom ApplicationUserManager like this

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to add user to multiple roles
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId">user id</param>
    /// <param name="roles">list of role names</param>
    /// <returns/>
    public Task<IdentityResult> AddToRolesAsync(string userId, string[] roles)
    {
        return yourrolestore.AddToRolesAsync(userId, roles.GetStringArray());
    }
```

Because like you wrote, UserManager didn't know your defined UserStore. You must do the link manually

### EDIT

When you extend UserManager you MUST specify the type of Key. So in your case type this :

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser, int>
```

And normally you will found your overload method with **int** key in parameter.

Comment: I understand that in order to expose the overload from the UserStore to my controller I have to extend the ApplicationUserManager with the same overload.

However I still can't reach the overload in the UserStore through `ApplicationUserMAnager.Store` from the extended method in the ApplicationUserManager.

Hope this makes sence